# Since which version is the conditional operator available in Java

Tags: java, conditional-operator

I have used the conditional operator in many places within my Java application. Now I have doubt whether it is compatible with all Java versions or not. In other words, I wanna know since which version the conditional operator is available in Java.

Comment: With Java the only version you might need to worry about would be 4 which doesn't support a lot of things. But the core language that takes large parts of the C syntax have always been the same.

Comment: Thanx Joey. Thanx for the edits too. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is available since the first release of Java. i mean java 1.0

Comment: Gotcha. Thanx Chandra Sekhar.